# How to convert a unescaped string to NSString in lldb?

Tags: regex, escaping, lldb, expr

Suppose I have a

```
" aaaaa
  vnnvnvnvnv
  bbbbc
"
```

How can I convert it to a `NSString` and use it in next `expression`, normally I need to escape it use a tool first.

I found the return char always break interpreter parse expression.

Comment: From this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37195597/4002113), I think can't do this in lldb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do multi-line expressions in lldb by typing just `expression`.  Then you'd type it just like you would type it in a source file.  e.g.

```
(lldb) expression
Enter expressions, then terminate with an empty line to evaluate:
1 NSString *test = @"\
2 hi\
3 there\
4 ";
5 NSLog (@"%@", test);
6 
2016-05-12 10:14:13.757 errteir[2052:170287] hithere
```

Comment: But I really need a unescaped return  in the string, not just multi-line expressions.